# Ansible docker_image - Building for Specific Platform

Tags: docker, ansible

Trying to build a docker image using Ansible's community.docker collection where the task takes place on an amd64 host but the docker image build is for arm64 targets.

I have created the following task:

```
- name: Tag and Push Docker Image {{ project.group }}/{{ project.name }} Version {{ version }} Build {{ build }}
  docker_image:
    name: '{{ project.group }}/{{ project.name }}'
    repository: '{{ registryIpPort }}/{{ project.group }}/{{ project.name }}:{{ version }}-BUILD-{{ build }}'
    tag: '{{ version }}'
    force_tag: yes
    push: yes
    source: build
    build:
      path: /home/ansible/git/{{ project.group }}/{{ project.name }}
      pull: no
      platform: arm64
```

However, when I run the task I get error:

**"Unsupported parameters for (docker_image) module: platform found in build. Supported parameters include: args, cache_from, container_limits, dockerfile, etc_hosts, http_timeout, network, nocache, path, pull, rm, target, use_config_proxy"**

Looking in [community.docker.docker_image](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html#parameter-build/platform) it says that platform was *added in 1.1.0 of community.docker*.

My installation is made up as follows:

`ansible-galaxy` version `2.9.6`

`community.docker` collection version `1.7.0`

--- UPDATE ----

I think the error is in the second line:

`docker_image:`

Which should be:

`community.docker.docker_image:`

Not sure why this is the case but, prepending `community.docker.` in that line makes the error goes away.

Comment: yes, the build: platform is in the code in master branch, https://github.com/felixfontein/community.docker/blob/main/plugins/modules/docker_image.py line 834. i have no idea sorry.